# End-to-End Reactive Streaming RESTful service (a.k.a. Back-Pressure over HTTP)

Tags: scala, rest, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I have been trying to clarify this question online for a while without success, so I will try to ask it here.

I would like to find some resource or example where it shows how I can build an end-to-end fully back-pressured REST service + client. What I mean is that I would like to see that, given a REST client that implements Reactive Streams (whether in Akka, JS, or whatever), I will have (and be able to "visualise") the back-pressure handled throughout a REST server built, e.g. with Akka-Http.

To be clear, I am searching for something like the following talk (but I could not find slides or videos to confirm it): http://oredev.org/2014/sessions/reactive-streaming-restful-applications-with-akka-http

My doubts with most examples I see are about the fact that I can find plenty cases where the REST service (server) is using Akka Http and Akka streams for the back end, but I am not sure that the backpressure is "communicated" over HTTP and REST, if the client is implementing Reactive Streams. In such situation, would I have a single "stream" bridged over TCP/HTTP or just 2 independent streams? That is my main doubt and confusion.

Hopefully I was clear enough and someone will be able to shed some light on the matter.
In any case, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried asking this question on the Akka Users Google groups page?  You might have better luck there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You’ve arrived in the right place to ask Akka questions :-)

There are two talks I’m aware of which show a demo how the backpressure mechanism really works when working with http.

1) One is [Roland Kuhn’s talk on ScalaDays SF 2015](https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/akka-http-reactive-web-toolkit): 
the backpressure over http demo starts around the 44th minute of this talk.

2) [My talk from ScalarConf Warsaw 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnTSuYL4_wU). the streams part begins around the 18 minute,
and the backpressuring demo is seen around the 24th minute. It shows a “fast processing” and “slow processing” server, in which you can see the
curl client being backpressured when the file is being uploaded (I use a file as an example because it’s a nice “big request”).

The back pressure is propagated to the client thanks to TCPs built in mechanisms for this - on the server side we simply do not read from the socket
until demand is available, which causes the back pressure to be propagated properly.

I hope this helps!